# ContentResolver query method cannot be used, NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0, android-contentresolver

I am creating an app that reads the phone contacts of your phone. However, for reasons that I don't know, I have a problem using the `query` method because of the api version that I used. It says that `Call requires API level 26 (current min is 16): android.content.ContentResolver#query`.

Here's my code I used in the oncreate method.

```
public void searchContacts() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            Log.i("try", name + " = " + number);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }



    cursor.close();
}
```

I know it should work since the tutorials that I have been watching has a lower API version than mine.

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "raymundo.elsa.elsa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'gr.pantrif:easy-android-splash-screen:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.liuguangqiang.cookie:library:0.1'
}
```

Here's the error in my logcat.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: raymundo.elsa.elsa, PID: 2303
                      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.ContentResolver.query
                          at raymundo.elsa.elsa.FillUpEmergencyContacts.searchContacts(FillUpEmergencyContacts.java:130)
                          at raymundo.elsa.elsa.FillUpEmergencyContacts.onCreate(FillUpEmergencyContacts.java:52)
                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method).
    Application Terminated.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are three flavors of `query()` on `ContentResolver`. The [four-parameter flavor that you are using](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) is new to Android 8.0 (API Level 26).

The five-parameter variant has been around since API Level 1, and the six-parameter variant has been around since API Level 16. You may wish to switch to one of those.

Comment: Could you explain what is to be provided in `queryArgs` parameter? Is it just selection arguments, but in Bundle instead of String array?

Comment: @getsadzeg: I guess so. I have not used that particular `query()` flavor personally.